# How to append word to URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following URL:

```
https://example.com/nl/products/stones?color_id=13
```

I want it to be:

```
https://example.com/nl/products/stones/white-stones
```

So I have to delete the GET variable and append "white-stones" to the URL.

Currently I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color_id=[^&]+&?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=302,L]
```

Which outputted: `https://example.com/nl/products/stones`

But now I want to append "white-stones" to this result.
How can I do this? In my research I found out that QSA should do that, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Is it only this single id you want to translate?

Comment: @eckes Yes, indeed!

Comment: The %1 would match anything after the Id, so `RewriteCond ... ^color_id=1(&?(.*)) RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/white-stone?%2 [R=302,QSA,L]` maybe? But I admit Apache rewrite is so painful I will not try to debug it. You might find nginx much easier.

Comment: @eckes this returns me: `https://example.com/nl/products/stones/white-stone?color_id=13`

Comment: Then maybe without the qsa?

Answer (score 1):

> I have following URL: `https://example.com/nl/products/stones?color_id=13` I want it to be: `https://example.com/nl/products/stones/white-stones`

If it's just this specific ID/URL then you presumably need to check for this specific ID and URL in your directive? This also greatly simplifies the requirement.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color_id=13$
RewriteRule ^nl/products/stones$ %{REQUEST_URI}/white-stones [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) discards the original query string from the request.

Or, could there be more query string parameters that you wish to maintain? Could this apply to any URL? This isn't explicitly mentioned in your question, but your directives hint at this. This would require a slightly different approach.

> In my research I found out that QSA should do that

The `QSA` (Query String Append) simply appends (ie. *merges*) the query string from the original request with any query string you are assigning in the *substitution*. This would not seem to be what you require here.